# Feature vector formulation for a Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, categorical-encoding

So I'm implementing a simple ANN where I have a massive input data set. The input data contains all kinds of stuffs like eg: **categorical values**: button,table, image...; **binary values**: true-false...; **continuous variables**: length, width...; **tuple values**: rgb(1,0,0),...; **text values**: file name, absolute location...

So my question is how do I take care of this different types of input data, like for
binary values- we can directly encode it to o-1, 
categorical use 1hot encoder to encode to 0-1 matrix. 
But how do I take care of continuous variables, tuple values and texts ??

And can I parse the date to one single Neural network?

Comment: Data feature engineering is like a whole field of study by itself. I'm not sure you will get a concise answer to your question here. It really all depends on the data and some cross validation helps you figure out what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous variables in NNs are usually scaled. For example by normalization, which squeezes them within a given range, or standardization, which forces their mean and variance to be equal. What works best is problem dependent.

Combining a network with such "regular" data and also convolutional layers for processing RGB channels of an image, can be done by having two separate parts to a network. The first processes your image with convolution, maxpooling, etc., and the other part could simply be one or several fully connected layers. *After* the convolutional part of the network, you can then combine these different parts by simply concatenating them.